# A subset sum algorithm which uses negative and positive integers

Tags: java, algorithm, subset-sum

The checkNum is the target value. array is the array of integers i am looking at. I am using the matrix to hold True and False value to see my possible sums. The checkPower method is only checking if the index i+1 is = 2^n. I am having trouble writing an algorithm that can solve the subset sum problem using negative integers also. I wrote an algorithm but I cannot use it, because as the input size increases I am running out of memory. I was wondering if anyone came up with an algorithm to solve the problem. I would prefer if it was written java, or it could be a pseudo code.

```
    public static ArrayList<Integer> populateArray(boolean[][]matrix, int []array, int checkNum){

        int usedElement = 0;
        ArrayList<Integer>resultArray = new ArrayList<>();


        for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++){

                if(checkPower(i+1)){
                    matrix[i][usedElement] = true;
                    usedElement++;
                    if(array[usedElement-1] == checkNum){
                        resultArray.add(array[usedElement-1]);
                        return resultArray;
                    }


                }
                else{
                    int tempSum = 0;
                    int remainingIndex = (int) (i - Math.pow(2, usedElement-1)); 
                    matrix[i][usedElement-1] = true;
                    tempSum += array[usedElement-1];

                    for(int k = 0 ; k < matrix[remainingIndex].length; k++){
                        if(matrix[remainingIndex][k]){
                            matrix[i][k] = true;
                            tempSum += array[k];
                        }   
                    }
                    if(tempSum == checkNum){
                        for(int j = 0 ; j < matrix[j].length; j++){
                            if(matrix[i][j]){
                                resultArray.add(array[j]);
                            }
                        }
                        return resultArray;
                    }
                }

        }
        return resultArray;

    }
```

Comment: If the numbers are too big for int, try `BigDecimal` or `BigInt`. If you're really out of memory, you can increase it. Many "hard" problems are hard for this reason, so most likely you'll only put off the eventual out of memory error.

Comment: Can you describe the algorithm you came up with?

Comment: It doesnt have to deal with the integers. My integer numbers are between -10 and 10. The number of possible subsets I am looking at is too big. For instance if I have 80 integers as inputs, I need to find all the possible sum  subsets which would be the summation of 2^(80)+ 2^(79)+ 2^(78)...... and so on. I am not sure whether I am doing it correctly.

Comment: Sorry I just now added my code.